# Python lxml error when iterating through xml file

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have an xml file like this:

```
<location type="journal">
???INSERT location???
    <journal title="J. Gen. Virol.">
        <volumn> 84 </volumn>
        <page start="2305" end="2315"/>
        <year> 2003 </year>
    </journal>
</location>
```

I am iterating through the file like so:

```
tree_out = etree.parse(xmlfile.xml)
updatedtext_head = '???UPDATE FROM '
insert_head = '???INSERT '
delete_head = '???DELETE '

updatedattrib_head = '???UPDATE '
updatedattrib_mid = ' FROM '
mark_end = '???'

every = 60

G = nx.DiGraph()


color_list=[]


node_text=[]


inserted_out=[]


deleted_out=[]


updatedtext_out=[]


others_out=[]


updatedattrib_out=[]


old_new_attrib_pairs=[]


full_texts=[]

for x in tree_out.iter():
        
    for y in x.iterancestors():
        if '???DELETE' in y.text and x not in deleted_out:
            deleted_out.append(x)

    if '???DELETE' in x.text and x not in deleted_out:
            deleted_out.append(x)

    for y in x.iterancestors():
        if '???INSERT' in y.text and x not in inserted_out:
            inserted_out.append(x)

    if '???INSERT' in x.text and x not in inserted_out:
            inserted_out.append(x)

    if '???UPDATE FROM' in x.text and x not in updatedtext_out:
            updatedtext_out.append(x)

    if  '???UPDATE ' in x.text and ' FROM ' in x.text and '???' in x.text and x not in updatedattrib_out and x not in updatedtext_out:
            updatedattrib_out.append(x)

    if (re.search(r'^\s+$', x.text)) and x not in others_out and x not in deleted_out and x not in inserted_out and x not in updatedtext_out and x not in updatedattrib_out:
        others_out.append(x)
```

but when I encounter elements such as this:

```
<page start="2305" end="2315"/>
```

I get thrown this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-b66a7d063b5b> in <module>
    121             deleted_out.append(x)
    122 
--> 123     if '???DELETE' in x.text and x not in deleted_out:
    124             deleted_out.append(x)
    125 

TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

The intended end result is that I want the elements in the list to be sorted into separate lists as I have done in the code segment above. Why does this error occur and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit

The `TypeError` is caused by the attribute-only element. Specifically, the element is represented by the variable `x` and the code tests whether `'???DELETE'` occurs within `x.text`, but `x.text` is `None` because the `text` attribute is where the element's content is stored. For reference, XML elements have the following structure:

```
<element-name attribute1 attribute2>content</element-name>
```

The error contains the message `argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable` because `in` has the syntax `value in iterable`. Specifically, `x.text` must be an `iterable`.

You should test that `x.test` isn't `None` before trying to use it like a `str`.

```py
if x.text is not None and '???DELETE' in x.text and x not in deleted_out:
    deleted_out.append(x)
```

#### Original

You never declared `deleted_out`. Try this:

```py
tree_out = etree.parse(xmlfile.xml)
deleted_out = []

for x in tree_out.iter():
        
    for y in x.iterancestors():
        if '???DELETE' in y.text and x not in deleted_out:
            deleted_out.append(x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I didn't add the declarations in the original post. I have edited it to include the declarations. The same error still persists.

Comment: Then the only other statement in line 123 that can create that error is `'???DELETE' in x.text`. Try printing out `x.text` just before the exception is raised. What is its value?

Comment: Here's your problem: `<page start="2305" end="2315"/>` has no text, it's an attribute-only element, so if it's parsed as `x`, `x.text` will be `None`. You need to test that `x.text is not None` before attempting to search it for a string.

Comment: Thanks! it finally works! It seems that my program doesn;t work with "x.text !=None" as a check but "x.text is not None" works.

Comment: You should always use `is` to check equality of `True`, `False`, and `None`: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations. I'll update my answer to reflect the comments.